# Directory access is forbidden. Laravel is showing this message on php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

I installed a Laravel project and it' of laravel 5.4 version. First it didn't had any server.php file and I got it from other project. Now that I have it and try to run it gives this error that Directory access is forbidden.

I added this line:

```
      (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')
```

But it's still giving this error.

Comment: check the folder permissions

Comment: I changed the permission of /usr/share/php to 777 . But it's still giving this error

Comment: you have to check the permission on your project

Comment: I changed the permission of my project to 777 but the error is still the same.

Comment: It is only for public folder. I don't know what's wrong with it.